# Can I configure Django runserver to reload when static or non-python files are changed?

Tags: python, django

By default, Django's `runserver` command auto reloads the server when python <del>or template</del> files are changed.

Is it possible to configure Django to extend its file monitoring for this purpose to other directories or sets of files<del>, such as JavaScript or CSS files being served statically (during development)</del>?

*This would be useful in this scenario: the Django app reads a set of static text files on startup and I would like the server to re-read them when they change, without having to add this specific feature - simply restarting would be fine.*

Do I need to start meddling with (or extending) `django/utils/autoreload.py` ?

Comment: If memory serves, there is no reason to reload for static files, as it merely serves the file directly from the filesystem.

Comment: The `runserver` doesn't need to be reloaded to serve updated static files or templates. It loads those files from the filesystem on every request

Comment: It doesn't restart when template files change, as there is no need. Exactly the same is true of static files.

Comment: I realise that I wasn't clear enough with this! I wasn't solely talking about serving static files - that was a bad and miselading example. A different use case would be: the Django app reads a set of static text files on startup and I would like the server to re-read them when they change, without having to add this specific feature - simply restarting would be fine.

Comment: It's mentioned here. See here for Django Docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#serving-static-files-with-the-development-server

Comment: I've added a better example to the question, to get away from the misleading example of serving static files.

Answer (score 1):

The static files are automatically served from disk, so there is no need to reload the dev server.

But your browser has it's own cache, and is keeping some of your static files in it...
To reload it use this shortcut :

**Ctrl + Shift + r**
 OR
**Ctrl + f5**

If your on mac use **CMD button** instead of **ctrl**

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reload server, but sometimes there is need to copy static files to be visible for the server.

Instead running `collectstatic` while developing, which copy recently edited static files (like javascript) from one directory to the directory, used by server.

here is a trick:

- link source directory to behalf of the target (will "override" target directory)
- or run in loop:

`python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

then your server will see all changes in files.

Comment: collectstatic is only for production

Answer (score 0):

The file will by default be read from disk on every request, so there is no need to restart anything.

There is a caching template loader, but it is disabled by default. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on your question say, Django always pulls the file from the filesystem on every request, so they are not cached.

However, there is a check (in`django.views.static`) for the mtime of the file if the browser sends an If-Modified-Since header which is why you may be seeing 304 Not Modified.

Regardless, would simply disabling  browser caching meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is YES, all you need to do is `touch` your settings file which will trigger a **runserver** reload.  If all you need to do is source new static files, you don't need this, but if you need to trigger a reload for another reason, it is possible with a simple touch.